# A Perl subroutine has a constant as parameter, how to display the constant name in the subroutine?

Tags: perl

A simple case :

```
use constant MYCO => "myco value";
...
sub example {
   my $var = shift; # contains "myco value"
   # here I would like to print the constant name passed, so "MYCO"
}
...
example(MYCO);
# example(OTHER_CONSTANT1);
...
```

added line for posting
added line for posting
added line for posting

Comment: What if they did `example("myco value");`?

Comment: What if there's also `use constant ALIAS => "myco value";`?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581628/access-name-of-a-constant-not-only-its-value

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this without explicitly providing the name of the constant as part of its value.

You could do something like:

```perl
use constant MYCO => ["myco value", "MYCO"];

sub example {
   my $var = shift; # contains "myco value"
   say $var->[0]; # value
   say $var->[1]; # name
}

example(MYCO);
# example(OTHER_CONSTANT1);
```

To be honest, this is sort of an anti-pattern in my eyes. I would much prefer to have a sub-routine (which is kind of what Perl does under the hood for constants, but makes no guarantees). And then just call the subroutine by name as the parameter.

```perl
sub MYCO { "myco value" }

sub example {
    my $constant_name = shift;
    my $value = __PACKAGE__->can($constant_name)->();

    say $value;
    say $constant_name;
}

example('MYCO');
```

*Edit*: After thinking about this a bit more, you may want to OO-ify your constants if you really need this functionality. Something like:

```perl
package My::Constant;

sub name { shift->{name} }
sub value { shift->{value} }

sub new {
    my ($class, $name, $value) = @_;

    my $self = {};
    ($self->{value}, $self->{name}) = ($value, $name);

    return bless($self, $class);
}

1;
```

Then in your existing code, you can define constants a little more idiomatically like:

```perl
use My::Constant;

use constant MYCO => My::Constant->new("MYCO", "myco value");

sub example {
    my $var = shift;

    return unless ref($var) eq "My::Constant";

    say $var->name;
    say $var->value;
}

example(MYCO);
```

Comment: Thank you, but imagine many many constants used in the example subroutine as parameter, the code could be very longer with this artifice ..... I just wondered if a pre-defined function was existing for that, with just one call in the subroutine

Comment: You need to change your approach, if you have a ton of constants, and need their names you should probably refactor.

Comment: This is how I typically do it.

Answer (score 2):

The question makes no sense unless

- you're limiting yourself to a specific subset of constants,
- they all have unique values, and
- you don't care if the constant was actually used or not.

Then you could do something like

```perl
use constant;

my ( %widget_types, %widget_type_by_val );
BEGIN {
   # Can't have two widget types with the same value.
   %widget_types = (
      FLOOB => 0,
      GRINK => 1,
      BLARP => 2,
   );
   
   %widget_type_name_by_val = reverse( %widget_types );

   constant->import( \%widget_types );
}

sub get_widget_type_name_from_val {
   return $widget_type_name_by_val{ $_[0] };
}
```

You could place that in a module which exports the constants.

```perl
package My::Widgets;

use constant;
use Exporter qw( import );

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(
   get_widget_type_name_from_val
);

my ( %widget_types, %widget_type_by_val );
BEGIN {
   # Can't have two widget types with the same value.
   %widget_types = (
      FLOOB => 0,
      GRINK => 1,
      BLARP => 2,
   );
   
   %widget_type_name_by_val = reverse( %widget_types );

   constant->import( \%widget_types );

   push @EXPORT_OK, keys( %widget_types );
}

sub get_widget_type_name_from_val {
   return $widget_type_name_by_val{ $_[0] };
}

1
```

There might be a module that does something like this for you already.